# How to delete elements by ID?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of ids

```
IEnumerable<long> ids
```

How can I delete from a table where the ID matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "standard" way according to the MSDN docs is to use those IDs to pull up each of the objects, then delete them with the DeleteObject command:

```
context.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList().ForEach(context.DeleteObject);
```

This will produce N+1 roundtrips to the DB. This is a common downside of ORMs; they're excellent at 99% of everyday use of SQL by an app (querying for results, creating/updating/deleting single objects) but are not really designed for these bulk operations.

You could also construct a query using ExecuteStoreCommand, where you `"DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN @p1"` and specify the list of IDs as a parameter.

Comment: how this works exactly? i get two errors with this, one context does not have a where method and overload resolution failed for DeleteObject

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `Id` as primary key in your entities and you have an entity called `SampleEntity` you could do something like this:

```
foreach(long id in ids)
{
  var sampleEntity = context.SampleEntities.SingleOrDefault( e => e.Id == id);
  if(sampleEntity!=null)
     context.SampleEntities.DeleteObject(sampleEntity);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF does not support batch operation, so you will have to delete entities one by one, or alternatively do a direct store query (SQL) to make the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Generically

```
var db = GetYourDBContext();
var ItemsToDelete = (from id in ids
                     from item in db.TableWithItems
                     where item.id == id
                     select item).ToList();

foreach (Item item in ItemsToDelete)
    db.DeleteObject(item);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like,

```
context.Entities.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.id))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(e => context.SampleEntities.DeleteObject(e) );

context.saveChanges();
```